# How do I keep a pointer to an element in an array that is returned from a function?

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers

I have a large array. I give this array to a function that returns a pointer to a specific element in the array. Or, at least this is what should happen. Instead the pointer I get after the function returns is 0x0000. What?!

```
int* getPtr(int[] array)
{
    //there is guarenteed no indexOutOfBounds...
    fixed(int* p = array[4])
    return p;
}


Main()
{
    int[] massive = new int[10];
    int* p = getPtr(massive);
    Console.WriteLine((int)p);        //... address is 0... arg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try giving the array some Values first. If you just write out a pointer to a memory location that has no data in it, there's no real guarantees on what you get back.

Answer (score 0):

The pinning done by `fixed` only lasts until the end of the controlled statement (or block). So your code is equivalent to:

```
fixed(int* p = array[4]) {
    return p;
}
```

After your function returns, the pinning is no longer in force. From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> After the code in the statement is executed, any pinned variables are unpinned and subject to garbage collection. Therefore, do not point to those variables outside the fixed statement.

Comment: So should I also fix the array in Main?

Comment: Sure, that sounds like a plausible approach. What happens if you do that?